# run script before shutdown on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have a sh script to ask something that the user has to press the button "yes" or "no".

I want to show it, when the user try to shutdown ubuntu. If the answer is "yes" the process go on and will shutdown the computer but if the answer is "no" the computer won't shutdown.

I don't know where i have to put the script to do that.

My sh script:

> if zenity --question --title "Have you do the homework?" --text
>   "homework"; then  echo "yes"; else   echo "no"; fi
>
> echo "return value was $?"

Answer (score 0):

You can run scripts on shutdown by placing them on `/etc/rc6.d/`. Add  `shutdown -c` at the beginning of your script and check the answer, retrigger the shutdown if the answer is "yes".